# How to dynamically update Listview based on json response in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm newbie into flutter and creating an flutter app which should show list of custom items as shown in the image.

1. Screen has a PageView created dynamically based on json response of key value **areas**
2. Now from same reponse inside **areas**, using **categories** key value have to create list items

**Help will be appreciated**

[Screen Shot Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYads.png)

**Json Response**

```
{
    "data": [{
        "areas": [{
                "customer_form_template_audit_area_id": 1,
                "audit_area_id": 1,
                "title": "Back-Up & Receiving Area",
                "description": "Back-Up & Receiving Area Description.",
                "categories": [{
                        "customer_form_template_micro_category_id": 1,
                        "micro_category_id": 1,
                        "micro_category_title": "Surface Swab",
                        "micro_category_description": "Surface Swab."
                    },
                    {
                        "customer_form_template_micro_category_id": 2,
                        "micro_category_id": 2,
                        "micro_category_title": "Hand Swab",
                        "micro_category_description": "Hand Swab."
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "customer_form_template_audit_area_id": 2,
                "audit_area_id": 2,
                "title": "Bakery",
                "description": "Bakery Description.",
                "categories": [{
                        "customer_form_template_micro_category_id": 1,
                        "micro_category_id": 1,
                        "micro_category_title": "Surface Swab",
                        "micro_category_description": "Surface Swab."
                    },
                    {
                        "customer_form_template_micro_category_id": 2,
                        "micro_category_id": 2,
                        "micro_category_title": "Hand Swab",
                        "micro_category_description": "Hand Swab."
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

**Code**

```
class Micros extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MicrosState createState() => _MicrosState();
}

class _MicrosState extends State<Micros> {

  List<String> litems = [];

  PageController _pageController = new PageController();

  Future<List<Areas>> _fetchQuestions() async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.encodeFull(ServiceConstants.GET_QUESTIONS),
      headers: {"Content-Type":"application/json", "Authorization":ServiceConstants.AUTH_TOKEN},
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200){

      Questions myClass = Questions.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));

      List<Data> listOfData = myClass.data;

      return listOfData[0].Areas;
    }
    else if (response.statusCode == 401){
      // Un Authorized request
      throw Exception('Un Authorized request');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 8,
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 6.0, 20.0, 0.0),
                      child: new SizedBox(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: new RaisedButton(
                            textColor: Colors.white,
                            color: Colors.green,
                            child: Text('Add'),
                            onPressed: () {

                            }),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 5.0, 20.0, 0.0),
                    child:  new Container(
                        height: 30.0,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        child: SizedBox(
                          width: double.infinity,
                          child: OutlineButton(
                            child: Stack(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                    child: Icon(Icons.chevron_left,
                                        color: Colors.white)
                                ),
                                Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                                    child: Text(
                                      "Micros Name", style:TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 12.0,
                                        color: Colors.white),
                                    )
                                ),
                                Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                    child: Icon(Icons.chevron_right,
                                      color: Colors.white,)
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            /*child: Text("Audit Area Name", style:TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 12.0)
                            ),*/
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.grey
                            ),
                            onPressed: (){

                            },
                          ),
                        )
                    ),
                  ),

                  Flexible(
                    child: FutureBuilder(
                      future: _fetchQuestions(),
                      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
                        if (snapshot.hasError) {
                          return Text('Error ${snapshot.error}');
                        }
                        else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          return new Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 5.0, 20.0, 0.0),
                            child: Container(
                              child: PageView.builder(
                                physics: new AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                controller: _pageController,
                                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                  print('@@ index '+index.toString());
                                  return Text('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA');

                                },
                                onPageChanged: (int index) {
                                  print('@@ on page changed $index');
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        }
                        else{
                          return CircularProgressIndicator();
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  )

                ],
              ),
              // color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: You can achieve your output with the help of streambuilder and fluturebuilder.

Comment: @HardikKumbhani, Please share any related sample will be very helpful(I am new to flutter)

Comment: can you tell me what exctly  you want, so as per your requirement i will send you whole code

Comment: @HardikKumbhani, I want to design the screen as in the above shared image 
1. Below Micros name, need to have multiple pages as horizontal scroll (Pages should create dynamically based on server response)
2. In each Page have to create a dynamic ListView with Spinner, TextFiled and Icon to upload images for that particular list item (List items should create dynamically based on response)

Pages are created based on key value of "areas" Here, it should create two pages
Page 1 - two list items (key value "categories")
Page 2 - two list items (key value "categories")

Comment: @MohammedZaheer Any update on this ?? i have similar use case

Comment: @PruthviKumar - Yes i have achieved this. No issues now

Comment: Can you share the solution here pls @MohammedZaheer

Comment: Sure, can you share your response here. so, that i can take a look and guide for same. @Pruthvi